# Can we see the group data in pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy object

Tags: python, pandas

Can we check the data in a `pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy` object?

Comment: you did not try ?

Comment: I tried but not able to print out the values for SeriesGroupBy.

Answer (score 15):

**First option**: iterate over all groups.

```
for name, group in df.groupby(column):
    print(name)
    print(group)
    print('\n')
```

**Second option**: if you want to see the group for a specific value, use the `get_group` method.

```
df.groupby(column).get_group(name)
```

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just use

```
df.groupby(column).head()
```

It [shows you the first n rows (default: 5).](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html)

Answer (score -2):

Just adding list() should help but the structure isn't super useful in its raw form. It returns a list of tuples with index.