# Is there a simple way to manually iterate through existing pandas groupby objects?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, iterable, manual-testing

Is there a simple way to **manually** iterate through **existing** `pandas` `groupby` objects?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'category': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B']})
grouped = df.groupby('category')
```

In the application a `for name, group in grouped:` loops follows. For manual-testing I would like to do something like `group = grouped[0]` and run the code within the for-loop. Unfortunately this does not work. The best thing I could find ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55971179/iterate-over-a-subset-of-a-pandas-groupby-object)) was

```
group = df[grouped.ngroup()==0]
```

which relies on the original DataFrame and not soley on the groupby-Object and is therefore not optimal imo.

Comment: How about `get_group` as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40630950/5276797)?

Comment: @IanS it helps when I know the name of the groups. But it would we way more convenient just to pass a number.

Comment: can you create a dict of groups with a factor, example `d={f"group{i}":g for i,g in df.groupby(df.category.factorize()[0])}` and then call each group like `d['group0']`

Comment: @anky_91 So you suggest to build a second groupby object using `factorize()`, right? Is it possible to use the existing groupby-object to build such a dictionary?

Comment: @Qaswed the dict in my comment is using the dataframe directly, not a second groupby. :)

Comment: You can try `unique_cats = df["category"].unique()` and then `df[df["category"] == unique_cats[0]]` and get the result since while using `df.groupby("col").apply(myfunction)` does the same thing iteratively. So there will be no difference.

Comment: @anky_91 By "second groupby", I mean that it doesn't use the existing `grouped`.

Comment: @Qaswed the answer in the comment doesnot use the `grouped` it uses the dataframe from the scratch and does a groupby

Comment: @anky_91 Thank you for your suggestion to build the groupby object differently. I clarified my question that I want to know, how one best iterates through **existing** groupby objects.

Comment: what do you mean by "manually iterate" *exactly*. you showed an *indexing* operation. Just create a list out of your groupby object. If you want to access it by group label, create a dict.

Comment: In the end it's unclear to me why you need this at all. Since you're iterating manually, why not select a group by name rather than by some arbitrary index? A group is just a subset of the dataframe anyway.

Comment: And if you must absolutely use an index, then run the loop `for name, group in grouped` and break when you have reached the number of iterations you're interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any iterable (here the GroupBy object) can be turned into an iterator:

```
group_iter = iter(grouped)
```

The line below will be the equivalent of selecting the first group (indexed by `0`):

```
name, group = next(group_iter)
```

To get the next group, just repeat:

```
name, group = next(group_iter)
```

And so on...

---

Source: https://treyhunner.com/2018/02/python-range-is-not-an-iterator/